# Eloquent ORM: Obtain a object, not an array of objects

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have this statement in Laravel 4:

```
$prepayment = Prepayment::where('hash', '=', $custom)->take(1)->get();
```

But this return an array of objects, and I want only one object, because there are only one result with the hash that I search.

How is the way to obtain only one object, not an array of objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the first() method instead of the get() method

```
$prepayment = Prepayment::where('hash', '=', $custom)->first();
```

Comment: You can skip the `take(1)` when using `first()`.  `$prepayment = Prepayment::where('hash', '=', $custom)->first();` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good article to learn more about how the eloquent orm works. http://laravel.io/topic/14/how-eloquent-relationship-methods-work It describes how the belongs to relationship will just give you one object whereas the has many relationship will give you an arrray of objects